# Customise Buttons on Global Action

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, global-actions

I've created a global action that pulls up content from a VF page inside of Salesforce1, triggered by viewing a record, clicking *+* and then clicking on the custom icon.

The page displays fine, except that it always has an active 'Cancel' button and a greyed out 'Submit' button. I simply want a 'Back' button there instead, which would go back to the record regardless of any VF navigation the user performs. Is this possible or will I have to wait for a future update?

Comment: what's the difference between pressing the cancel or having a back navigation? I would to both the same right? Also, know that you could enable the submit button of the publisher action window via the Force.com Canvas SDK: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_sdk_publisher_events.htm .

Comment: Thing is I want to display information only, so have nothing to do with Submit and Cancel isn't exactly user friendly. That aside, Cancel doesn't even seem to work!

Comment: I see. If it's just displaying information, my first idea would be to use mobile cards instead but you probably have a good reason why you wanted to show the page in a publisher action? Fact that the cancel isn't working is somewhat troubling :).

Comment: The content displayed is dynamic based on the record being viewed... will look at cards though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Summer '15 you can hide the header in Visualforce custom actions by setting the showQuickActionVfHeader attribute to false (see the [Summer '15 Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/custom_actions_vf_pages_remove_pub_header.htm)).

So you could hide the buttons and then add a "back" button in your VF page that basically does the same thing as cancelling. Not perfect, but at least less confusing for the end user.